# Which is the extension class for GetCookies method in Dot.Net Core 3.1 API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I am Implemented Getcookies method in code but it is not working in core 3.1. this given error `IheaderDictionary` does not contain a definition for `GetCookies` and no accessible extension method. Same Code Working in dot.net framework project.

Below is Code :

```
User=Attempt(Controller.Request.Header.GetCokkies(ImpersonationCookies).FirstOrDefault()?.Cookies.FirstOrDefualt()?.Value)??user
```

Anyone have any suggestion on this. Search lot of content in Internet but no not getting any solutions

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get cookie in .net core,here is a demo:

Actions:

```
public void SetCookie()
        {
            var option = new CookieOptions();
            option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
            Response.Cookies.Append("Key", "key1", option);
        }
        public void GetCookie()
        {
            var key = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Key"];
        }
```

result:
[image]